# Lost keystore in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am using android studio 1.4 and I made a keystore but I accidently deleted that folder. Now how can I make a new keystore? I use android studio just for the purpose of learning as of now. I have no recent plans to publish on google play. I am trying to create new keystore but I am not able to create a new keystore. Please help me out with this problem.

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: This is the error i get "keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file exists, but is empty: C:\Users\personal\Documents\key store"